# How to set focus on button after scrolling list view (Set Visibility)

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android and I am using list view with one text view and button.I am performing some visibility stuff where after clicking on button1 it will hide the button1 and show button2.

Set visibility **View.GONE** and **View.VISIBLE** is working perfectly but problem is occurring when I scroll my list view magically it is reseting all button1 to **View.VISIBLE** state.

Please anyone help me to overcome with this problem.

**Code:**

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View 
 view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view == null) {
        holder =  new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater parentInflater = (LayoutInflater) mctx.getSystemService(mctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = parentInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemname_child_layout, null);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

   holder.button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   holder.button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

   //initial button state
   holder.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   holder.recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }

   view.setTag(holder);

 return view;
}
```

Comment: try to use recylerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have record of the clicking of button because when you scroll listview it refreshes to the previous stage.

So declare a variable universally in your adapter class like this:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList();
```

Now set list of 0 till the adapter size

```
    for(int i=0;i<adapter.size;i++){
     count.add(0);
     }
```

Then after clicking on button1 set your button visibility like this:

```
              holder.recordBtn.setTag(position);

     if(count.get(position)==0){
         holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
         else{
         holder.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         holder.button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }

       holder.recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         int pos = (int)view.getTag();
         if(count.get(pos)==0){
         count.set(pos,1);
         holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
         else{
         count.set(pos,0);
         holder.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         holder.button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
      }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for answer it is working partially, when I click on buttton1 it is hidding and showing button2 fine cool. And because of button1 click count is set to 1. When I click  **button1 of next series**  it is failing to hide  because after clicking previous button1 I updated count qual to 1. So now I need to click twice on button1 of next series to make it button2. Have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Try this...i have edited your code

```
 @Override
 public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View 
 view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view == null) {
        holder =  new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater parentInflater = (LayoutInflater) mctx.getSystemService(mctx.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = parentInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemname_child_layout, null);
        holder.button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


   //initial button state
   holder.button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   holder.recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

         holder.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }


 return view;
}
```

Comment: thanks Pratik for your answer.. Can you explain me what exactly you are doing here with button1 and button2.                                                                                                holder.button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);                                holder.button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

Comment: @MithunWalawalkar see i have again edited my answer and you were calling getTag() before setTag().Every time you have to first getview and setTag() and then getTag()

Comment: Nope I changed my code but also facing same problem.